# Помогите найти ошибку. . Ввести пять целых чисел, найти максимальное из них. Пример: Введите пять целых чисел: 1 5 4 3 2 Максимальное число 5

Tags: pascalabc.net

```
a1, a2, a3,a4,a5, max : integer;

begin
write ('Введите пять чисел: ');
readln (a1, a2, a3,a4,a5);

if a1 > a2 then
    max := a1
else
    max := a2;

if a2 > a3 then
    max := a2
else
    max := a3;

if a3 > a4 then
    max := a3
else
    max:=a4;

 if a4 > a5 then
    max := a4
else
    max := a5;


writeln ('Максимальное из них: ', max); 

end.
```

Comment: Возьмите бумажку и ручку, пройдите по всем шагам вашей программы и выпишите значение всех переменных на каждом шаге.

Comment: Хотя сильно подозреваю, что задание на умение пользоваться массивами и циклами

Comment: @Денис-Подгородский Вы перезатираете максимум, а вы должны каждое число сравнивать с максимумом.

Answer (score 1):

Как сказали в комменте, нужно сравнивать с максимумом. Здесь я задал максимумом первое число а далее сравнивал с этим максимумом остальные числа.

```
var a1, a2, a3,a4,a5, max : integer;
begin
write ('Введите пять чисел: ');
readln (a1, a2, a3,a4,a5);
max := a1;
if a2 > max then
max := a2;
if a3 > max then
max := a3;
if a4 > max then
max := a4;
if a5 > max then
max := a5;
writeln('Максимальное из них: ', max)
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Это лучше осуществить с помощью массивов, следующим образом:

Для начала прочитаем все цифры в один массив

```
for i:=1 to 5 do
  read(numbers[i]);
```

Далее прировняв первое число массива к `max`, будем искать значения больше `max` в массиве:

```
max:= numbers[1]
for i:=1 to 5 do
begin
  if (numbers[i] > max) then
    max:= numbers[i];
end;
```

Готово.